# Convert sql to Zend_Table

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, q

How can I convert this:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (latitude - [startlat]), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * ([startlng] - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM TableName HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;
```

to Zend_Table.

I have two keys, lat and long in the database and I want to get the data which is close to the user,the query works provided by the first user which converted it yo Zend_Table but if I have data from people which **are in the same city** it doesn't return any data, I guess the query needs to be improved, to also show results for a bigger distance

```
$this->select()->from(array('c' => 'content'))......
```

I have noe idea how to do this,  can you guys help me?

//LE

```
$data2->setIntegrityCheck(FALSE)
        ->from(array('c' => 'content'), array('location', 'id', 'user_id', 'date', 'attachment', 'content','lat','long'))
        ->columns(array(
            'distance'  => "SQRT(POW(69.1 * (lat - {$location['lat']}), 2) + POW(69.1 * ({$location['long']} - long) * COS(lat / 57.3), 2))"
        ))
        ->having('distance < ?', 25)
```

It looks like the query is wrong for finding users close to you, this one should do the trick

```
ASIN(
SQRT( POWER(SIN((@orig_lat -
abs( 
dest.lat)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(@orig_lat * pi()/180 ) * COS( 
abs
(dest.lat) *  pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((@orig_lon – dest.lon) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))

as distance
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tested with ZF 1.12.4-dev, PHP 5.3.26, MySQL 5.6.13**

```
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($adapter);
$table = new Zend_Db_Table("TableName");

$startLat = 39.0;
$startLng = 122.0;

$select = $table->select()
    ->from($table, array("latitude", "longitude",
        "distance" => "SQRT(
            POW(69.1 * (latitude - $startLat), 2) +
            POW(69.1 * ($startLng - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2))"))
    ->having("`distance` < ?", 25)
    ->order("distance");

$rowset = $table->fetchAll($select);

print_r($rowset->toArray());
```

**Tested with ZF 2.2.5-dev, PHP 5.3.26, MySQL 5.6.13**

```
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;

$table = new TableGateway("TableName", $adapter);

$startLat = 39.0;
$startLng = 122.0;

$rowset = $table->select(
    function (Select $select) {
        global $startLat, $startLng;
        $select->columns(
            array(
                "latitude",
                "longitude",
                "distance" => new Expression("SQRT(
                    POW(69.1 * (latitude - ?), 2) +
                    POW(69.1 * (? - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2))",
                    array($startLat, $startLng))
                )
            );
        $select->having->lessThan("distance", 25);
        $select->order("distance");
    }
);

print_r($rowset->toArray());
```

**Test data and test SQL query (without PHP):**

```
use test;

drop table if exists TableName;

create table TableName (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    latitude numeric(9,4) NOT NULL,
    longitude numeric(9,4) NOT NULL,
    key (latitude,longitude)
);

insert into TableName (latitude, longitude) values
(10.0, 10.0),
(20.0, 20.0),
(30.0, 30.0),
(40.0, 40.0),
(50.0, 50.0),
(60.0, 60.0),
(70.0, 70.0),
(39.2, 122.2);

set @startlat = 39.0;
set @startlng = 122.0;

SELECT latitude, longitude, SQRT(
        POW(69.1 * (latitude - @startlat), 2) +
        POW(69.1 * (@startlng - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM TableName
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance;
```

**Output of SQL test:**

```
$ mysql -E < 19057187.sql
*************************** 1. row ***************************
 latitude: 39.2000
longitude: 122.2000
 distance: 17.484284526375415
```

**Output of PHP test:**

```
$ php 19057187.php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [latitude] => 39.2000
            [longitude] => 122.2000
            [distance] => 17.484284526375415
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [latitude] => 39.2000
            [longitude] => 122.2000
            [distance] => 17.48428452637566
        )

)
```

Comment: A real master here, the keys with the latitude and longitude need to be double or float? right now I have them as float

Comment: I tried with both... and it doesn't return any data...and the users have the same lat and long in the database so it should find them...

Comment: I have added my tests above.  First just a SQL test to make sure the query works.  Then the output of the ZF1 and ZF2 code.

Comment: Note that I used NUMERIC(9,4) above, but I just tried changing the test to use FLOAT, and it works fine with that too.

Comment: I suggest you test by commenting out the HAVING clause so it would return all data regardless of distance.  Then see what value it returns for the distance.  You may have made a typo error in the formula, so it's much larger for some reason.

Comment: I tried that, if I take out the HAVING it returns all data...from the database, if I add HAVING it doesn't return any data, I will accept and award your bounty, and do more debugging, because I made a typo or so...I don't know yet, but great answer, great quality Sir, that's true help.

Comment: Make a clone of your table (`CREATE TABLE TableName2 LIKE TableName`), and load it with a relatively small subset of sample data.  I often do this when developing and testing a query.  Querying the whole table is too hard to test because data sets are large.  Then when you get the query working, you can edit it to query the real table and work on optimizing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$select = $db->select();
$select->from('TableName', array('latitude', 'longitude'));
$select->columns(array(
    'distance'  => "SQRT(POW(69.1 * (latitude - {$startLat}), 2) + POW(69.1 * ({$startLong} - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2))"
));
$select->having('distance < ?', 25);
$select->order('distance ASC');
```

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long) * COS(lat / 57.3), 2)) AS `distance`, `ud`.`first_name`, `ud`.`last_name`,' at line 1 in C:\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 228